# Running manifests (classes) from a task or plan in Puppet Enterprise

Tags: puppet-enterprise

### TL;DR

In Puppet Enterprise, how do I run a manifest (testpp.pp) from a task or plan (not Bolt).

```
plan base_windows::testplan (
  TargetSpec $targets,
  Optional[String] $contents = undef,
  String $filename,
){
  $apply_prep($targets)
  $apply_results = apply($targets, '_catch_errors' => true) {
    class { 'base_windows::testpp': }
  }
  $apply_results.each | $result | {
    notice($result.report)
  }
}
```

`apply_prep` seems to succeed, but `apply` is failing with the following error:

```
{
  "msg" : "Evaluation Error: Unknown function: 'report'. (file: /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/orchestration-services/code/environments/development/modules/base_windows/plans/testplan.pp, line: 16, column: 19)",
  "kind" : "bolt/plan-failure",
  "details" : {
    "class" : "Bolt::PAL::PALError"
  }
}
```

If I change the code to:

```
plan base_windows::testplan (
  TargetSpec $targets,
  Optional[String] $contents = undef,
  String $filename,
){
  apply_prep($targets)
  $apply_results = apply($targets, '_catch_errors' => true) {
    # Is this how to call a class? I cannot find an example.    
    class { 'base_windows::testpp': }
  }
  $apply_results.each |$result| {
    $target = $result.target.name
    if $result.ok {
      out::message("${target} returned a value: ${result.value}")
    } else {
     out::message("${target} errored with a message: ${result.error.message}")
    }
  }
}
```

The plan tells me it has failed, but there are no errors in the node's report. In fact, there is no entry for the time the plan was executed.

I cannot find any examples on how to call a class from a plan, so the above `apply()` is a guess, based on [this](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2019.8/writing_plans_in_puppet_language_pe.html#applying_manifest_blocks_from_a_plan) documentation.

I have installed the `puppetlabs_reboot` module and successfully ran a plan using it, therefore, I conclude my system is set up correctly, it's just my code that is wrong.

### Background

I may be going about this all wrong, so here is some background to the problem. Currently, I have a series of manifests that install various packages from the public Chocolatey repository depending on a node's classification. Package definitions are stored in Hiera data and each package' version is set to `latest`. At the end of the `Package{}` resource, some manifests include a reboot.

These manifests are used to provision new nodes and keep existing nodes up-to-date with the latest package version.

The Puppet agent is set to run once per hour and if the source package is updated in the Chocolatey repo, on the next Puppet run, the manifest will update the package, rebooting the node, if required.

#### Goal

- New nodes are provisioned with the latest package version.
- Prevent package updates at undetermined times on existing nodes.
- Continue to allow Puppet agent runs every hour.
- Make use of existing manifests.

#### Ideas

Split out the `package{}` code from the profile manifest and place them in tasks / plans, allowing packages to be updated out-of-hours.

Specify the actual package version in Hiera. Although this is more declarative and idempotent, it means keeping an eye on over 100 package version. I guess it would be fairly simple to interrogate the Chocolatey repos with code to pull the latest version number, but even so I am no better off.

Create a task with a script that runs `choco upgrade all`, however, the next Puppet run would revert package versions according to the version defined in Hiera, meaning Hiera still needs to be kept up-to-date.

#### Problems

As per the main crux of this question, how do I run manifests (classes) from plans? If I understand correctly, tasks are for ad-hoc scripts, whereas plans can run tasks and manifests. As a lot of time has been invested in writing manifests, I would prefer not to rewrite all my manifests as scripts.

I am confused by the Puppet documentation as it seems to switch between PE and Bolt syntax. I am using Puppet Enterprise where Puppet says [they don't recommend using Bolt](https://puppet.com/docs/bolt/latest/bolt_configure_orchestrator.html) but their examples seem to site Bolt commands.

No errors in the node' report. `apply_prep()` reports executed successfully, albeit taking far longer to execute than `puppetlabs_reboot` module, but `apply()` results in a failure, but nothing is logged in the node's reports.

Using `puppetlabs_reboot` module as a reference, it appears their plan uses a bunch of tasks. It appears that they don't use `apply()` to run their `reboot{}` class. Is this not duplicating the work?

---

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas, I'd be grateful if you could share.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it to work. The class I was trying to run, required parameters that I hadn't provided!

```
plan base_windows::testplan (
  TargetSpec $targets,
  Optional[String] $contents = undef,
  String $filename,
){
  
  apply_prep($targets)

  $apply_results = apply($targets, '_catch_errors' => true) {
    class { 'base_windows::testpp':
      filename => $filename,
      contents => $contents,
    }
  }
}

# Output the whole result_set in the PE console
return $apply_results
```

I found this out using the logs.

1. Turn on debug level logging in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/logback.xml` (`root level="debug"`)
2. Tail the following logs:

   1. `tail -f /var/log/puppetlabs/bolt-server/bolt-server.log`
   2. `tail -f /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.log | grep -B 5 -A 5 'testplan'`
   3. `tail -f /var/log/puppetlabs/orchestration-services/orchestration-services.log`